# Why are there two worlds separate from one another

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, death, olam-haba-world-to-come, afterlife

HaShem created an Olam HaZeh/Yemos HaMashiach/Le'asid Lavo world, and He also created an Olam Haba/Gan Eden world.

Why is it necessary to have two worlds that do not interact with each other? What is the point of keeping the living from mingling with the dead?

Granted that after the sin Adam introduced death into the world, but perhaps

(1) HaShem could have made it that after 120 man becomes some
sort of an ethereal state in which he gets rewarded and punished for his previous actions while still being able to interact with this world.

Or (2) perhaps there could be some settlement in the middle of nowhere where the "dead" live, and they can interact with the outside world.

Or (3) perhaps leave it as is, with two worlds, but allow some level of interaction between them without sorcery.

Why make two worlds that are completely separate from one another?

Comment: Is there some perceived downside? If not, you could just as easily ask "why make echidnas", or billions of other such questions...

Comment: I think one "incentive" is hinted in Pirkei Avot (forgot exactly which Mishnah) that says that *olam hazeh* is merely like the hallway for the "banquet" in *olam haba*. In a sense, creating a dichotomy may be advantageous. The physical side of humanity toils in olam hazeh so that it can gain the reward for mitzvah performance which is reserved in olam haba. To truly appreciate that reward, the body needs to be completely spiritual, which cannot be done in *olam haza* since the physical "distracts" the spiritual.

Comment: I have clarified and formatted your question. The main point you are asking about seems to be the lack of interaction between the two worlds. Can you provide a source for that lack of interaction?  Or if you disagree with the edit - roll it back.

Comment: @DonielF The overall goal of each world is the same, namely to know G-d. The more ethereal state of existence removes the aspect of separation, to be yachid. G-d, in His kindness, gave us a perception of being completely separate and independent to have a type of knowledge about G-d that the angels don't experience.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Doesn't answer why they can't interact with one another. (And a source would be great.)

Comment: Did you intend to group *yemoth hamashiach* and *l'athid lavo* together with *olam hazeh*? (The Maharal actually describes *yemoth hamashiach* as a transition between *olam hazeh* and *olam haba*.)

Comment: @Loewian I know it's not the best groupings, especially since everyone disagrees on what they are. My intention was the events of this world, including the future of Mashiach and thereafter, as opposed to the Olam Ha'Emes.

Comment: In that case, I think you're characterization may be at best disputed. I believe Artscroll has a pretty nice summary of some of the key positions in their volume on perek Chelek of Sanhedrin.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @DanF, perhaps we can begin an answer based on two mishnayoth in [Avoth (4](http://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.4?lang=bi):16-17):

> רַבִּי יַעֲקֹב אוֹמֵר: הָעוֹלָם הַזֶּה דּוֹמֶה לִפְרוֹזְדוֹר בִּפְנֵי הָעוֹלָם הַבָּא. הַתְקֵן עַצְמְךָ בַפְּרוֹזְדוֹר כְּדֵי שֶׁתִּכָּנֵס לַטְּרַקְלִין
>
> Rabbi Yaakov says: This world is like a hallway before the world to come. Fix yourself in the hallway so you may enter the drawing room.
>
> הוּא הָיָה אוֹמֵר: יָפָה שָׁעָה אַחַת בִּתְשׁוּבָה וּמַעֲשִׂים טוֹבִים בָּעוֹלָם הַזֶּה מִכָּל חַיֵּי הָעוֹלָם הַבָּא. וְיָפָה שָׁעָה אַחַת שֶׁל קוֹרַת רוּחַ בָּעוֹלָם הַבָּא מִכָּל חַיֵּי הָעוֹלָם הַזֶּה
>
> He would say: One hour of repentance and good deeds in this world is better than all the time in the world to come. And one hour of pleasure in the world to come is better than all the time in this world.

In *olam haba*, also called *olam ha'emeth* - the world of truth, man has no free will as he knows the truth as it is and can chose freely no more so than can an angel.  In contrast, in this world, the *olam hasheker*, the seduction of falsehood is ever-present. Man can only develop who he is by choosing good and truth when there is a genuine challenge in that choice.  If he were in regular communication with those who are already in *olam ha'emeth*, there would no longer be such a challenge, and there would no longer be such a merit.